# Vagrant VirtualBox Local Dev Env, Ubuntu, Yarn, Vue CLI 3 - Issues

Tags: vue.js, vagrant, virtualbox, yarnpkg, vue-cli-3

I am trying to setup a local development environment consisting of:

- Ubuntu server vagrant box
- My existing vuejs project created using Vue CLI 3 and passed to vagrant via `synced_folder`
- Then run yarn run serve and access this on my host using port forwarding on the vagrant box.

**Background:**
I have developed a vue CLI 3 project on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop which is working well, however, I want to move this inside of a vagrant box to keep my local machine tidy. I currently use `yarn run serve` which works well. I want to be able to run this command inside a new vagrant development environment.

**Summary of Problems/Issues:**

- the `vue` command is not found after installing its dependencies
- permission issues spat out by yarn when attempting to run `yarn run serve` inside vagrant box
- there is an `fsevents@1.2.4` message when `yarn global add @vue/cli`

**Provisioning the local dev environment:**

The `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "webserver_dev" do |webserver_dev|

        webserver_dev.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
        webserver_dev.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
        webserver_dev.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8888
        webserver_dev.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
        webserver_dev.vm.hostname = "develop.dev"

        webserver_dev.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

        webserver_dev.ssh.forward_agent = true

        webserver_dev.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.memory = "1824"
            vb.cpus = "2"
        end
    end
end
```

Provisioning of the vagrant box: `ubuntu/xenial64 (virtualbox, 20180802.0.0)`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev -y   

# install node and npm:
cd ~  
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh  
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh    

# install yarn
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -  
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn    

# Show installed versions  
yarn -v  (outputs 1.9.4)  
node -v  (outputs v10.9.0)  
npm -v  (outputs 6.2.0)
```

**Problems/Issues Output:**
When I navigate to my existing vue project folder and run `yarn run serve` inside vagrant ssh I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.9.4
$ vue-cli-service serve
/bin/sh: 1: vue-cli-service: Permission denied
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I run `sudo yarn run serve`
(I shouldn't have to run this as root anyway but:)

```
yarn run v1.9.4
$ vue-cli-service serve
/bin/sh: 1: vue-cli-service: Permission denied
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Running `vue --version`

```
vagrant@cc:~$ vue --version
No command 'vue' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vpe' from package 'texlive-latex-extra' (universe)
vue: command not found
```

Output from running `yarn global add @vue/cli`
As shown in the official vue-cli installation [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)
**NOTE:** The `fsevents@1.2.4` message I get. Could this what is causing the problems?

```
vagrant@cu:~$ yarn global add @vue/cli
yarn global v1.9.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/617(node:7694) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "@vue/cli@3.0.1" with binaries:
      - vue
Done in 58.25s.
```

**Summary:**
Has anyone out there achieved a local development environment where they are successfully able to run `yarn run serve` inside it and access the result on their host machine?

I would be very interested to see how other developers approach their local development for vue js projects which also have other services requiring reverse proxys (eg node js app running on a different port).

I have spent an awful lot of time trying to set this up to no avail. Maybe these tools just don't play well together. If you think you could help I would be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: You installed everything with sudo but attempt to run / install without using sudo. You shouldn't have run `sudo` when you installed everything

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy, let me try without using sudo and cross my tear covered fingers

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - It seems like after reading the documentation of nodesource and yarn that they both instruct you to install using sudo in their installation instructions. I tried to install them without sudo but they require it. Do you have any other ideas or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary Workaround:** - inspired by this [post](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/713#issuecomment-338285554)

After further troubleshooting I found the problem is certainly a permissions related issue (not related to vue-cli).
I think that as my vagrant is using virtualbox, there is a virtualbox issue with symbolic links from the synced folder from my host, which may change permissions and stops `chmod` command from having any effect on files. In my case the execute flag from node_modules/.bin directory was not-executable.

For anyone with similar issues here is my **current workaround** to this issue (Do yourself a favour and read https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/713 I wish I'd found it earlier!):

1) copy the projects `package.json` to: the yarn global directory: `/home/vagrant/.config/yarn/global/`

```
cp /var/www/project/package.json /home/vagrant/.config/yarn/global/
```

2) Install the projects dependencies globally in the yarn users directory:

```
cd /home/vagrant/.config/yarn/global
yarn install
```

3) Now returning to the project and running `yarn run serve` works as it uses the node_modules from `/home/vagrant/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/` which has the correct executable permissions.

```
cd /var/www/project/package.json
yarn run serve
```

**Example of cause of the issue:**
1) Change directory to your project and ls -l to see permissions:

```
cd /var/www/project/node_modules/.bin
ls -la
```

Outputs:

```
lrw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant    18 Aug 29 00:21 which -> ../which/bin/which
```

2) Attempt to make file executable:

```
chmod 777 ./which (adding sudo doesn't make this work either)
```

Outputs:

```
lrw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant    18 Aug 29 00:21 which -> ../which/bin/which
```

**OLD ANSWER - DIDN'T WORK:** The solution I am now using is taken from here: [Source](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/713#issuecomment-17296765)

Adding this to the Vagrantfile enables symbolic links to work properly.
I am using ubuntu on my host and guest machines so can't be sure this will work for Mac and Windows.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end
```

**Further Reading:**

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/713

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo` when installing `vue-cli`.

The `vue-cli` documentation at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html states that:

> To install the new package, use one of the following commands. **You
>   need administrator privileges to execute these unless npm was
>   installed on your system through a Node.js version manager** (e.g. n or
>   nvm).
>
> ```
> npm install -g @vue/cli
> # OR
> yarn global add @vue/cli
> ```